# cfsdaacdfawd virus. usb flash file and folder keeps coming back after being delete?

Tags: usb

I got a silicon power 16gb usb flash and it has a bad virus in it. I called "cfsdaacdfawd". I have Windows 10 with bitdefender total security 2015.

tried everything to format it, BUT NOTHING WORKS.

I have tried these:

1. CMD and diskpart.
2. 3rd party programs. (USB fix - Rufus - USB Format tool & ...)

[image]

3. partition manager. (partition manager 12 in safemode)
4. disabling write-protected in registry.

After plugging in the USB flash, antivirus detect the viruses and deleting them, but when I pull it out and put it in again, all my files and folders coming back again with the virus.

I even deleted the partition with "partition manager 12" in safe mode, but it automatically going to the same old format again and the files and folders are still remains.

More Information:

the virus folder name: cfsdaacdfawd

in the cfsdaacdfawd folder:  aiasfacoafiasksf.vbss

Bitdefender Knows the virus with this name: Trojan.Downloader.JQVE

The flash also has the .lnk virus and make as u see.
And the hidden files wont show up if i remove the flash and plug it in again.

when i'm trying to format it, right after i hit the format button, it looks like my taskbar gets refresh, i repeat my taskbar gets refresh, not desktop or my computer.
please help with some more Professional suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried to low-level format it? There's a great and free program called HDD Low Level Format Tool. Give it a shot. Have also in mind that the reason the virus is coming back is because it would have a background process running, check you Task Manager for some weird processes.

Comment: no. there is no process. when u trying to remove your memory safely from the task bar, if any process from that memory be on, then windows will say it to you. but in my case i cant eject my flash from taskbar real quick.

Comment: i also tried HDD Low Level Format Tool v4 and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it comes back, more than likely, is because your PC is infected. 
You should find an alternate scanner like Trend Micro Housecall or MalwareBytes Home to scan your system.

Comment: no. as i said my "bitdefender" works like a charm.

Comment: this has happened to one of my flashes.

Comment: if windows is infected the same must happen to my other hard drive as well.

Comment: Hard drive or flash drive? They may be treated differently based on the device type by the malware.

Comment: @SamanDinarvand The reality is that if you delete a file, can confirm it's been deleted (refresh or {dir} command) and later it reappears, there's a process creating that file. That could be a standalone process or a hijacked executable, or worse, a rootkit. The fact that one antimalware indicated nothing is not meaningful. Malware effectiveness if really only around 80%.

Comment: The other thing I notice is seemingly extensionless entries. Turn on to show extensions for know filetypes and repost the screenshot of the infected drive. You may be causing the infection yourself again by executing a malicious shortcut to what you look at as a valid file. You go to the View tab, then Options. On the second tab there, scroll down a little and uncheck "hide file extensions..."

Comment: i have "hide file extensions for known file types" unchecked. if u look those ones that haven't shown type at the end of their names ARE SHORTCUTS.

Comment: my hard drive, and other usb drive don't has this poblem.

Comment: it happened to this one only because this is the one that connected to a full of virus laptop.

Comment: when i'm trying to format it, right after i hit the format button, it looks like my taskbar gets refresh, i repeat my taskbar gets refresh.

Comment: If you're sure it's only that drive, then trash it. Unlikely but possible that its firmware is infected...

Comment: no i don't guess firmware has any issue. i'm 100% sure its a virus or something that prevent the flash being format by disconnect and reconnect it immediately.

Comment: my flash has unlimited warranty and i can get a new one any time. but i hate doing that because of a virus.

Comment: Again, a virus doesn't just "appear" on a flash drive... There is some malacious code somewhere that's executing. If you're certain it's not on your PC then the only alternative is that it's running on your flash drive. The only executable code on your flash drive would be in its firmware - unless again you autorun something upon insertion.

Comment: " as i said my "bitdefender" works like a charm" evidently not.